# Переменная в имени другой

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть несколько textbox'ов: TextBoxTovar1, TextBoxTovar2 и т.д. Хочу пробежать по ним циклом:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    Fill(TextBoxTovar[i].Text);
}
```

конструкция с квадратными скобками не работает. Как правильно записать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В WinForms контролы на форме можно искать по имени:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
    Fill(((TextBox)Controls["TextBoxTovar" + i]).Text);
}
```

будут найдены только тектбоксы, лежащие непосредственно на форме. Если нужно искать во другом контейнере (например, панели) - то нужно использовать свойство `Controls` этого контейнера, а не свойство формы.

Для WPF аналог Controls[name] это метод [FindName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname(v=vs.110).aspx) у окна или любого другого контейнера:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
    Fill(((TextBox)FindName("TextBoxTovar" + i)).Text);
}
```

FindName работает рекурсивно, так что он найдет не только элементы, лежащие на самой форме, но и элементы во вложенных контейнерах.

Comment: пишет: Имя "Controls" отсутствует в текущем контексте

Comment: Наверно, из-за того, что у меня WPF проект. Надо было указать в вопросе. Как поступить в данном случае?  И спасибо за помощь, в любом случае.

Comment: @Андрей дописал пример для WPF

Comment: Спасибо. Уже всю голову сломал :)

Answer (score 2):

Очень **странный** вопрос. Без **костыля** тут не обойтись думаю.

Но можно и при помощи `Linq`:

```
foreach (TextBox tb in Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(x => x is TextBox).Select(x=>x as TextBox)){
// do something 
}
```

Данный код переберет все `TextBox`в форме. 
Надеюсь поможет.

P.S если выберите этот вариант поиска, смогу более подробно рассказать/объяснить что к чему.

Comment: более короткий вариант - `Controls.OfType<TextBox>()`

Comment: @PashaPash солидарен